# Is it possible to show background Activity if I earse my view with transparent color in android

Tags: android, canvas, window, transparent, erase

I am calling a dimmed window from Serivce over any activity. Is it possible to show background activity while using transparent paint over canvas/view?
Setting Transparent paint using below code.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
    // setup initial color
    private final int paintColor = Color.BLACK;
    // defines paint and canvas
    private Paint drawPaint;
    // stores next circle
    private Path path = new Path();
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;


    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        setupPaint();
    }

    private void setupPaint() {
        // Setup paint with color and stroke styles
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(50);
        drawPaint.setAlpha(0);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float pointX = event.getX();
        float pointY = event.getY();
        // Checks for the event that occurs
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        // Force a view to draw again
        postInvalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Calling the above view from below service.
While using finger to draw transparent color over view, Noting happens, I want to show background activity in erasing part.

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
            PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    params.dimAmount = 0.5f;
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawing_view, null);
```

Please help me in this context.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say you "show" background activity ?

Comment: Suppose You have an activity A. On pressing floating icon, I am drawing a View B(Black Color) as overlay over activity A. Now I use my finger over view to erase Black color of view B. On erased Area, I want to show Background Activity A.